# No overload for method NewGuid takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, guid

How can I convert int (`StaffID`) to string in the below method. It wont accept `Guid.NewGuid(ToString)`

```
public void submitStaffID(StaffEnity staff)
{
    staff.StaffID = Convert.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid(ToString));
    StaffEntity.Add(staff);
}
```

> No overload for method NewGuid takes 1 argument.

```
namespace StaffEntity
{
    [DataContract]
    public class StaffEnity
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int StaffID;
        [DataMember]
        public string Forename;
        [DataMember]
        public string Surname;
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime TimeAdded;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAq_Z-dT67o im following this tutorial but instead of string I declared my StaffID as an Int. (5 minutes into the video)

Comment: Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9730264/601179), you can't convert `Guid` to int, I'm pretty sure you will get an exception in the conversion.

Comment: I rolled back to your previous question. **You can't edit a question to a new one because you're prevented asking new questions.** it's invalid edit which cause all of answers and comments looks stupid and unrelated.

Comment: ah ok first time I have ever had this 6 questions per day thing :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
staff.StaffID = Convert.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

But converting it afterward to int32 won't work!

> From MSDN:
>
> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all
>   computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such
>   an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.
>
> An int structure, on the other hand:
>
> Represents a 32-bit signed integer.
>
> So, you can't convert from Guid to int without loosing most of the
>   information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518684/convert-guid-to-int

You probably meant this

```
staff.StaffID = new Random().Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
```

Note for proper use of the `Random` class:
[Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

Comment: so what do i do if i want int as my staff id?

Comment: actually wait wouldnt it be convert int tostring

Comment: @Garrith. Use `Random` see my update

Comment: something like `staff.StaffID = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid);`

Comment: No I realised my mistake in the first attempt what I ment was to try convert my staffid (int) to string

Comment: @Garrith. that code will give you `string` and probably equals to `.ToString()` which you already have. You wrote you need an `int` and not a `string` .  ?

Comment: @Garrith. I got confused! **what are you trying to do?** get a random int? parse guid to int\string parse int t string? what?

Comment: In the video he creates a string ID but I changed it to Int StaffID what I need to do is convert my int to string using whatever the Guid.NewGuid is?

Comment: +1 for being first to mention that his method is actually wrong, but this is not a good idea either: `new Random().Next`.  The problem here is that, if he calls this many times quickly, he will get a bunch of duplicates because it uses the same seed each time.  Better to just not us a random number for the id to begin with or make the id a `Guid` and be done with it.

Comment: @Garrith. just take  your int and use it's `.ToString()` method. like this: `var theString = staff.StaffID.ToString();`

Comment: Yeah but I still dont know how to convert my staffID (int) to string using the Guid method?

Comment: @EdS.. You're right on the Random part, I just gave an example, I'll look for marc garvell anwer about it and add it to my answer.

Comment: @Garrith. **You can't use an int to get a `Guid` it's like taking a wheel and convert it to a car.** It can't be done. forget about the `Guid` if you're using `int`!

Comment: SO if I use Ed S method `Guid StaffId { get; set; }` as the DataMember how do I add staff to my StaffEntity list?

Comment: @Garrith. You need to create a `List<StaffEnity>` like with this: `var list = new List<StaffEnity>(); list.Add(staff);` Please open an new thread with an new question. stackoverflow complains with too much comments.

Comment: ugh your only allowed 6 questions in a 24 hour period now? God thats awful.

Comment: Ive updated this question to reflect what I need

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message is telling you the problem... `Guid.NewGuid` does not take any arguments.  You placed `ToString` inside the method call when you meant to place it after.

```
staff.StaffID = Convert.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Which of course won't work correctly as a `Guid` represents a 128-bit value, much too large for an int.

Why not make `StaffId` a `Guid` to begin with (not a `Guid` converted to something else, but `Guid StaffId { get; set; }`) or not a random value?

Comment: Yeah I have never understood it? I dont know what it means when it says arguement.

Comment: @Garrith: "Arguments" are what you pass to a function.  If I have `void Foo(int x)` and I call it like so `foo(10)` `10` is the argument that `x` represents inside of the function.

Comment: Yes it will work, leaving him with an exception one moment later... =)

Comment: @gdoron: And so he will... that I did not look into.

Comment: ok so if I do that do I just leave StaffEntity.Add(staff); in my submitstaffID area?

Answer (score 1):

I think `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` will work.

Comment: Yup it does thanks bud will accept in a few moments

Comment: Yes it will work, leaving him with an exception one moment later... =)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
staff.StaffID = Convert.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? What does the "`ToString`" variable represent?

Also, the `Guid.NewGuid` method doesn't have any arguments. The proper use would just be `Guid.NewGuid()` instead of `Guid.NewGuid(ToString)`.

This will generate a random GUID for you. If you are worried about collision, don't mind it. The chances of generating the same GUID twice are really small.

Answer (score 0):

ToString() is a method you apply on.

`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` should give you a new guid